# what is the shortcut key in LXDE to move a window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

I just move from gnome to LXDE. It is quite good, fast and light. But, some functions are lost in from gnome. For example, I can press Alt+F7 in gnome to move a window with keyboard or mouse. But, I can not do it in LXDE. Can I set it up in configure file?

Answer (score 9):

I did update `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` to contain

```
<keybind key="A-F7">
  <action name="Move"/>
</keybind>
```

in the section `<keyboard>`.

When reloading the [openbox](/questions/tagged/openbox) config with

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

i can press <kbd>Alt+F7</kbd> to move the window.

Comment: In Lubuntu 16.04 I have the settings in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and there is no the `lxde-rc.xml` file.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late ... but for whoever might be interested : Alt+click & Move does it !

Answer (score 3):

lxde doesn't provide a window manager, [read this](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=457).

Comment: Thanks. So, can I use openbox's window manager? Actually, I can use 'Alt + space' and 'move' to simulate 'Alt + F7'.

Comment: @HXGuo yes you can use openbox or any other window manager that you like

Comment: Could you tell me how to config it in lxde-rc.xml? thanks.

Comment: @HXGuo to be honest i used lxde once for like 2 weeks, so i didn't configure it or anything but you can watch this video http://youtu.be/YkOFStobVhI and read this http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201011/page09.html and this http://linux-commands.wikidot.com/howto-s:lxde if you need further help consider asking here http://unix.stackexchange.com/ those guys are expert in the linux world

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Space brings up Openbox menu, including Move option.